# Facebook PHP SDK v4 - session is null

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk

first of all, I realize this question have been asked before, but non of the answers that solved the original questions worked for me, so that is why I asked a new question.

I use a FB PHP SDK V4 for registering users to my web application. It was working fine, but several weeks ago it suddenly stopped working. I cannot say if it was on its own or it was some unrelated bugfix I did that acciedentaly broke it.

What is not working is the $helper->getSessionFromRedirect() - it always returns null with no error, even after the redirect back from FB, resulting in a redirection loop. I attached the code for registration bellow.

```
        Facebook\FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('{app_id}', '{app_secret}');
        $helper = new Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('https://www.someurl.domain/sign/registerFacebook');
        try {
            $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
        } catch(\Facebook\FacebookRequestException $ex) {
            $this->flashMessage('Nastala chyba při komunikaci se servery facebooku.', 'error');
        } catch(\Exception $ex) {
            $this->flashMessage('Registrace účtu se nezdařila. Zkuste registraci provéct znovu.', 'error');
        }

        if(!isset($session) || !$session) {
            $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'user_about_me','user_birthday'));
            $this->redirectUrl($loginUrl);
        } else {
            $user_profile = (new Facebook\FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me'))
                ->execute()->getGraphObject(Facebook\GraphUser::className());

            // business code for pre-filling registration form
        }
```

The problematic code is within the try {} block, $session is always empty, even after the second call of this method (after redirection back from facebook).

What I already tried:

- separating the method into two - one for getting the link and redirecting from facebook and one for landing from facebook - same result
- every possible combination of www/non-www URL - both in the code and in the app settings on FB

I suspect it has something to do with HTTPS, since a transition to encrypted traffic occured in this webapp a while ago. But application always uses HTTPS for every request and I have HTTPS in app settings on FB, so I don't see anything wrong with it.

Can somebody help? I would much appreciate it!

Thanks, Johny

Answer (score 0):

In your case the sdk is successfully setting a session key `FBRLH_state`but failing to retrieve and authenticate because of `non-www` domain issue.

It is either because the script generating login url is on non-www and the login-callback.php url you passed to the `getLoginUrl()` function is a www version of your website or vice-versa.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I have already chcked this and both the original script which generates the URL and the callback are with "www". In fact, all URLs in given application are automatically HTTPs and "www" prefixed (this is achieved partly in htaccess and partly in routing framework).